# Referring a model into a form field in django-userena

Tags: django, forms, python-2.7, models

I'm using django-userena authuentication. I'm trying to refer a gender defined model from models.py into forms.py to appear in user registration but it says SyntaxError at non-keyword arg after keyword arg (forms.py, line 23). I dont know how to refer it correctly. Please help!!!

models.py:

```
class Profile(UserenaLanguageBaseProfile):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (1, _('Male')),
        (2, _('Female')),
    )

    gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('gender'),
                                              choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
                                              blank=False,
                                              null=False)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from userena.models import UserenaLanguageBaseProfile
from accounts.models import Profile
from userena.forms import SignupForm

class SignupFormExtra(SignupForm):
    gender = forms.PositiveSmallIntegerField(label=_(u'Gender'),
                                             'gender',
                                             required=True)

    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'First name'),
                                 max_length=30,
                                 required=True)

    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Last name'),
                                max_length=30,
                                required=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

try forms.ChoiceField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField

```
class SignupFormExtra(SignupForm):
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(label=_(u'Gender'), choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=1
                                         required=True)
```